# aiohttp client in global scope for GCP Cloud Function Gen 2 (connection pooling)

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, aiohttp

I would like to use Gen 2 Cloud Function and `aiohttp` to take advantage of high concurrency. However, I am struggling to set up the connection pool correctly using `aiohttp` because of its `ClientSession` syntax.

GCF allows you to create a connection object in the global scope so that it can be reused by all concurrent and subsequent requests sent to the same *Cloud Run* instance processing the function requests. Google has published one documentation on HTTP connection pooling, which unfortunately uses `requests.Session`: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/samples/functions-tips-connection-pooling

Taking the same approach with `aiohttp.ClientSession` results in an error: `RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task`

To fix this, I wrote an async factory method `create_session`:

```py
session = None

async def create_session():
    global session
    if not session:
        session = aiohttp.ClientSession(base_url="https://example.com")
    return session

async def async_run(payload):
    await create_session()
    async with session.post("/", json=payload) as resp:
        data = await resp.read()
    return data

@functions_framework.http
def main(event):
    payload = json.loads(event.data.decode())
    asyncio.run(async_run(payload))
    return "done"
```

which succeeds for the very first request, and then fails on the rest (tested w/ Postman): `RuntimeError: Event loop is closed`

So my main question is: what is the proper way to set up HTTP connection pool for async in GCF?

That implies a few specific questions:

1. Does `requests.Session` in global scope block other concurrent function requests within the same *Cloud Run* instance? If not, I can simply ditch `aiohttp`...
2. How can I attach a running event loop to an existing `aiohttp.ClientSession`?
3. Is there a way to call `aiohttp.ClientSession.close` on "teardown", or should I trust GCF to properly close connections on function termination?